# Labeling a point using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, I want to label the point (1,1) as "P."  (It is not exciting, I know. It is part of a graph that I want to draw.)  I have the code `\node[above right, outer sep=2pt] (1,1) {P};` to do this.  `TikZ` is putting the label above and to the right of the origin.

Why isn't TikZ putting the label above and to the right of (1,1)?

I have a grid placed on the Cartesian plane.  With `outer sep=2pt`, I expected that some of the grid would be obscured by the label P.  I want the letter "P" to stand out on the graph, and I think it would if some of the grid lines were obscured.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow] (-1.25,-1.25) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.25,2.25);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,2) +(0,0.5cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1) -- +(0,-0.5cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1,0) +(-0.5cm,0) -- (2,0) -- +(0.5cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\filldraw (1,1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
\node[above right, outer sep=2pt] (1,1) {P};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding e.g. `fill=white` to the node to obscure what's behind it?

Comment: @cfr  Now I did.  Thanks.  (I also added the option "circle.")

Answer (score 10):

You can obscure the grid lines behind the node using `fill=white`. You can also do this if you use a `pin` which will draw a line from the point to the label. Or you could use the `label` option which is similar but without the line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow] (-1.25,-1.25) grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5]  (2.25,2.25);
    \draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,2) +(0,0.5cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1) -- +(0,-0.5cm);
    \draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1,0) +(-0.5cm,0) -- (2,0) -- +(0.5cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};
    \filldraw (1,1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \node [fill, draw, circle, minimum width=3pt, inner sep=0pt, pin={[fill=white, outer sep=2pt]135:P}] at (.5,1) {};
    \node[above right=10pt of {(1,1)}, outer sep=2pt,fill=white] {P};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: labelling nodes]

Comment: Thanks for illustrating `label` and `pin`. I will refer to the manual for these options.  I want to get the "P" above and to the right of the point (1,1).

Comment: I am still not able to move the "P" to the appropriate position.  Why doesn't `\node[above right, outer sep=2pt] (1,1) {P};` do it?

Comment: @user74973 Have you tried `\node[...] at (1,1) {P};`?

Comment: @user74973: You are missing `at` before `(1,1)`.

Comment: @Harish Kumar  Yes, I forgot "at."  That was a waste of time.

Comment: @user74973 Sorry. I forgot that bit. See edited answer.

Comment: @cfr  I compared your code with the manual and didn't see that "at" was missing.  It happens.

Comment: @Harish Kumar  May you help me with one more edit?  How do you code so that the letters "P" and "Q" are typeset in the same color as the line segment between them - `green!20!white`.  By the way, to put the letters in italics, I have the options `label={[fill=white]left:$P$}` and `label={[fill=white]left:$Q$}`.

Comment: @user74973 Use `label={[fill=white,text=green!20!white]left:$P$}`

Comment: @Harish Kumar  I forgot the "text=" part of the specification.